# Simple question about a more efficient way to implement Expander Function in S-DES

Tags: c++, cryptography, des

SO, I'm implementing (Simplified)-DES in C++, and I've got a working Expander function. The expander function is defined as, given a 6 entry input (say, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, we output a new, 8 entry output in the following form: {1,2,4,3,4,3,5,6}. I have this implemented as follows, but I'm sure there is a much better, and likely faster way to implement this. Any suggestions?

```
void expandchars(std::vector<int> &vec){
std::vector<int> temp=vec;
vec={temp[0],temp[1],temp[3],temp[2],temp[3],temp[2],temp[4],temp[5]};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster way would be to avoid allocating a temp vector. If `vec.capacity() < 8` then your code is almost optimal. To make it optimal:

```
void realloc_expandchars(std::vector<int> &vec){
  // Optimal if vec.capacity() <8, since a reallocation is unavoidable
  std::vector<int> temp=std::move(vec);
  vec={temp[0],temp[1],temp[3],temp[2],temp[3],temp[2],temp[4],temp[5]};
}
```

If `vec.capacity() >= 8` then you probably want to avoid creating a new vector. For that, you might want to do something like:

```
void inplace_expandchars(std::vector<int> &vec){
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + 4, 2 /*count*/, 0 /* value */);
    vec[4] = vec[3];
    vec[5] = vec[2];
    vec[2] = vec[4];
    vec[3] = vec[5];
}
```

Possibly slightly slower, but more readable would be to use std::array:

```
void inplace_expandchars(std::vector<int> &vec){
    std::array<int, 8> temp = {vec[0], vec[1], vec[3], vec[2], vec[3], vec[2], vec[4], vec[5]}; 
    vec.clear();
    vec.insert(vec.begin(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```

And then combine it all:

```
   void expandchars(std::vector<int> &vec){
     if (vec.capacity() < 8)
         realloc_expandchars(vec);
     else
         inplace_expandchars(vec);
   }
```

Comment: So, if I understand  the first inplace_expandchars, it goes like this: first, we insert two 0s at the 4th, 5th positions, so we would go from {1,2,3,4,5,6} to {1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6}, and then replace {3,4,0,0} with {4,3,4,3}, giving {1,2,4,3,4,3,5,6}, if I understand that correctly? I'm pretty new to this C++ stuff, used to Mathematica/Matlab (:

Comment: @Shinaolord I haven't run it, but you are correct about the idea.